# objective-c how to save textfield values through textFieldShouldEndEditing:

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've a `UITableViewController` which has Save button. At present I'm displaying row's of  `UITableViewCell's`. `UITableViewCell` contains textfield . Let's say if user enters text in 1st table cell and hits "Save" then I'm losing the entered/modified text.
suppose I have a textField

```
((UITextField*)[cell viewWithTag:101]).placeholder = @"title";
((UITextField*)[cell viewWithTag:101]).text = arrayActivities[indexPath.row][@"title"]; //arrayActivities[indexPath.row];
((UITextField*)[cell viewWithTag:101]).keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
```

how I would save arrayActivites editable values??

Answer (score 0):

Keep one global dictionary dctGlobal in your class.
Set `textfield.delegate=self` in cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

And then get and save value for text field in following method

`- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField`

```
[dctGlobal setObject:textField.text forKey: textField.placeholder];
```

On save, Use dctGlobal for saving into database.

Thanks!

Comment: :(( its give me error... what is delegate in ((UITextField*)[cell viewWithTag:101]).text.delegate = self ?? and setObject:forKey??

Comment: remove this line and Set cell.textfield.delegate=self in cellForRowAtInxedpath method

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making the UITableViewController a UITextViewDelegate? So in your tableView's .h file:

```
UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

and in your .m file you should be able to call:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [array addObject: textfield.text];
}
```

Comment: UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> yes i do above thing but i have a UIViewController and i make a outlet of UITableView on UiViewController

Comment: If your controller is a UIView then do 
UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate>